# Blackjack simulator for probability of a dealer bust for each starting card

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, playing-cards, simulation

I came up with this solution to an exercise out of John Zelle's Python Programming book.

```
#bust.py --- Simulates multiple games of blackjack with each possible dealer starting card and estimates
#   the probability that the dealer will bust

import random

def intro():
    pass

def takecard():
    card = random.randint(1, 10)
    has_ace = False
    #Randomly choose if the 1 is an ace
    if card == 1:
        has_ace = random.choice([True, False])
    return card, has_ace

def sim_one_game(starter):
    #For simulating the ace
    if starter == 12:
        starter = 1
        has_ace = True

    total = starter

    while total <= 17:
        card, has_ace = takecard()
        total += card

        #Ace is valued at 11 when it would produce a stopping total
        if has_ace == True and total + 10 >= 17 and total + 10 <= 21:
            total += 10

    return total

def sim_n_games(starter, game_count):
    busts = 0
    for i in range(game_count):
        score = sim_one_game(starter)
        if score > 21:
            busts += 1
    return busts

def sim_each_card(game_count):
    bustsls = []
    for i in range(1, 12):
        bustsls.append(sim_n_games(i, game_count))

    return bustsls

def output(bustsls, game_count):
    print("Busts for Starting Card A: {} out of {} games. ({:0.1%})".format(bustsls[10], game_count, bustsls[10] / game_count))
    for card in range(1, 11):
        print("Busts for Starting Card {}: {} out of {} games. ({:0.1%})".format(card, bustsls[card - 1], game_count, bustsls[card - 1] / game_count))

def main():
    intro()
    game_count = int(input("\nHow many rounds to simulate? "))
    bustsls = sim_each_card(game_count)
    output(bustsls, game_count)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

It works pretty well, although when profiling it with 100.000 iterations, it takes ~5 seconds to finish. When profiling, I noticed that all the calls to `random` take up quite some time.

Does anyone know a better way to solve this? Please note that I am a beginner, and there are a lot of things I haven't learned anything about yet, but I'll read all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The code has excellent layout, partitioning into functions,
and you gave variables and functions meaningful names, for the most part.

### Naming

Consider a better name for the `bustsls` variable.  If it is just a list
of busts, then `busts` would be good.

### Input checking

It is good that you force the user `input` to be an `int`, but there is room for improvement.  For example, the code does not behave well if the user inputs unexpected values like `-5`, `0` or a word like `dog`.  You could extend the user input checking using a module like [pyinputplus](https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus/).

### Lint check

I ran [pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html), and it identified a
few long lines of code.

It also recommends f-strings over `format`.

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

I created a new function (`print_results`) to avoid repeating the code that calculates the percentage and formats the output.

### Documentation

You could use your `intro` placeholder function to print out some helpful information to the user.  It should also include a better description of the output.

---

Here is the code with some of the suggestions:

```
import random
import pyinputplus as pyip

def intro():
    print(
        'Simulates multiple games of blackjack with each possible dealer\n'
        + 'starting card and estimates the probability that the dealer will bust.'
    )

def takecard():
    card = random.randint(1, 10)
    has_ace = False
    #Randomly choose if the 1 is an ace
    if card == 1:
        has_ace = random.choice([True, False])
    return card, has_ace

def sim_one_game(starter):
    #For simulating the ace
    if starter == 12:
        starter = 1
        has_ace = True

    total = starter

    while total <= 17:
        card, has_ace = takecard()
        total += card

        #Ace is valued at 11 when it would produce a stopping total
        if has_ace == True and total + 10 >= 17 and total + 10 <= 21:
            total += 10

    return total

def sim_n_games(starter, game_count):
    busts = 0
    for _ in range(game_count):
        score = sim_one_game(starter)
        if score > 21:
            busts += 1
    return busts

def sim_each_card(game_count):
    bustsls = []
    for i in range(1, 12):
        bustsls.append(sim_n_games(i, game_count))

    return bustsls

def print_result(card, busts, game_count):
    ''' Print results for one card '''
    pct = busts / game_count
    print(f"Busts for Starting Card {card}: {busts} out of {game_count} games. ({pct:0.1%})")

def output(bustsls, game_count):
    print_result('A', bustsls[10], game_count)
    for card in range(1, 11):
        print_result(card, bustsls[card - 1], game_count)

def main():
    intro()
    game_count = pyip.inputInt("\nHow many rounds to simulate? ", min=1)
    bustsls = sim_each_card(game_count)
    output(bustsls, game_count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```